# What does the zero refer to in the code below

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I know this is a very basic question but what does the 0 refer to in the code below

```
var even = arr.filter(function(val) {
return 0 == val % 2;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> what does the 0 refer to

Here `0` refers to the `Number` 0.

```
0 == val % 2
```

will evaluate to `true` or `false` which you are returning.

Answer (score 1):

`0` is the tested value of `val` modulus (`%`) 2. When there is no "remainder", as with even numbers, it will return the number `0`. For odd numbers it will have a remainder of `1` and the function will return `false` to `filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is the modulus operator, it works like this

> The remainder operator (modulus) returns the first operand modulo the
>   second operand, that is, `var1` modulo `var2`.   **The modulo function
>   is the integer remainder of dividing `var1` by `var2`**

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_(.25))

In other words, if `val` can be divided by `2`, the modulus operator returns `0` as there is no remainder, that's why it checks for a zero

Turning the yoda condition around, it makes more sense

```
val % 2 === 0; // can be divided by 2, so it's even, returns boolean
```

For instance if `val` was `4`, `16`, `200` etc, it would be true, as `4` can be evenly divided by `2`.
If `val` was `3`, `9`, `201` etc. it would be false, as `3` can not be evenly divided by `2`.

Answer (score 0):

0 is just a number which is compared to right hand side expression **val % 2**

statement `0 == val % 2;` returns true if val % 2 is 0 (value of `val` is even), or returns false is val % 2 is 1 (value of `val` is odd)

**Just for information:** Modulo operator returns the remainder(a number) when `val` is divided by any number